# Adding image to an iOS App in cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to create an iOS app using Cordova and is running into a problem.

I have a cordova plugin in my project that has lot of image assets.

When i generate the Xcode project, these image are not getting properly added to the Xcode project.

Below is how I add image assets along with plugin.

```
     <source-file src="src/ios/MySDK/XIBs/MyViewController.xib" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/MySDK/libMy.a" framework="true" />
    <source-file src="src/ios/MiSDK/MiRes" />
    <framework src="AudioToolbox.framework" />
    <framework src="AVFoundation.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreGraphics.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreMedia.framework" />
    <framework src="CoreVideo.framework" />
    <framework src="MobileCoreServices.framework" />
    <framework src="QuartzCore.framework" />
    <framework src="OpenGLES.framework" />
    <framework src="Security.framework" />
    <framework src="ImageIO.framework" />
    <framework src="Foundation.framework" />
    <framework src="Foundation.framework" />
    <framework src="UIKit.framework" />
</platform>
```

In the snippet above, MiRes folder has all the image assets used by libMy.a.

Currently to get things working I have to add the image assets manually in the Xcode project.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Images or assets should be in the www folder of your cordova project. Did you make an iOS project and added in Cordova?

Comment: Thanks @Giri for the reply....the image assets are part of this third party framework I use...so it should be added into www folder?.... MiRes folder has other localizable folders internally.

Comment: I don't think you can add the whole folder with ```<source-file src="src/ios/MiSDK/MiRes" />```, I think you should add every image one by one or create a .bundle file with all of them and ```<source-file src="src/ios/MiSDK/MiRes.bundle" />```

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile for the answer. The third party library I am using does not have the resources in a bundle file. So I will have to add each of the asset individually..huh...was wondering if there was an easier method from the Cordova side....Or I could just add the assets from the Xcode project as that might be easier...(The library I use has 180 image assets)